# How to make a random uint64 to send to an EOS contract

Tags: smart-contract, eosjs, node

My friend had made an EOS contract and he has asked me to submit a random uint64, I need to generate this in nodejs.

Do I need to use a library like big number https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-number or or int64 https://github.com/broofa/node-int64 Ive read the docs and i just don't get it?

Do I then need to convert the number to hex before I send it to the contract?

Is there some library that will just give me a random uint64 ready to fire of to an EOS contract?

Would something like this do the job?

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
biguint = require('biguint-format')

const myUint64 = biguint(crypto.randomBytes(64), 'hex', { prefix: '0x' }); 

// myUint64 = 0x748eba3cfdc84c0d9ecd86a4878c7291649abee4c93417226af3ed2f31ec6e81c4ebafc770f77eb9aefec1662fc7fbb70e4b855589ef976d1ff88b88652a2262
```

Comment: It seems that you generate 64 bytes integer, but `uint64_t` means 64-bit (8 bytes) integer. If you pass uint64, you don't need to pass in hex string.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to generate a random uint64/ulong in Javascript like concatenating/multiplying the results of Math.Random() or Math.Floor() or using third-party-libs. But here's not really the right place to ask for these things as it's not directly eos-related.

You need to serialize and sign the whole transaction before you push it through chain to the smart contract.
You should take a look at eosjs https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs and probably look for some tutorials on how to use eosjs as it does all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to make a random int. I doubt your question means to make unique int as a value of identifier. If so, I am building a solution by making a sequence in eosio table. What do you think?

I think this [package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/eosjs-account-name) can help. There is a thing I need to finish. I will back to this thread once I get it.